# Appending a value if a key has already been submitted (checkboxes in a form) PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have an odd issue.  I have one PHP script that is used for multiple forms.  It takes in all the requests and then puts the data in the appropriate table in a database.  As it stands, it looks like this:

```
    $fields = "";
$values = "";

foreach ($_REQUEST as $key=>$value)
{


        $key = str_replace(":","",$key);
        $fields .= "$key,";
        $values .= "'$value ',";
}


//remove the ending comma from $fields and $values
$fields = substr($fields, 0, -1);
$values = substr($values, 0, -1);

$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $survey . " ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
mysql_query($sql)
    or die(mysql_error());
```

And this works well.  The problem is, there are some forms with checkboxes (i.e. a person can select more than one option).  If I were to use a get method, the query string would look like:

www.somesite.php?V9=1&V9=2&V9=4

With the current script, only 4 is taken, since it was the last value.

Now, I know a reason this is happening is because of the way the name of the checkbox is defined in the form.  It says name="V9"  instead of name="V9[]"  However, I cannot change the forms.  They are generated by software, and the idea is that any user can create an HTML form, point it to the script and their information will be recorded in a table.  So, changing the HTML is not an option for me.

So, I need a way to detect whether a key has been submitted, and if so, append the value.  I tried this:

```
    $fields = "";
$values = "";

foreach ($_REQUEST as $key=>$value)
{

        //check to see if the key has already been used for multi-choice questions
        $key_check = strpos($fields, "$key,");

        if($key_check !== false){
            $values = substr($values, 0, -2);
            $values .= "\;$value ',";
        }else{
            $key = str_replace(":","",$key);
            $fields .= "$key,";
            $values .= "'$value ',";
        }
}


//remove the ending comma from $fields and $values
$fields = substr($fields, 0, -1);
$values = substr($values, 0, -1);

$sql = "INSERT INTO " . $survey . " ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
mysql_query($sql)
    or die(mysql_error());
```

But I get the same results.  $key_check never seems to be valid.  Any help would be appreciated.  Someone here has a working ASP version that does a similar thing, but it emails the data, rather than saving it in a DB.

Comment: SQLInjection vulnerability Never take user data like $_GET $_POST $_REQUEST and use it in an sql query unless it has been escaped or used in a prepared query.

Comment: Append `[]` to the names of the form controls, and they will magically become arrays...

Comment: I'd recommend forgetting about `$_REQUEST` and always using only `$_POST` or `$_GET` - depending on what is neccessary right away (You can use `$_POST` and `$_GET` within the same script but be sure the `$_POST` data could not be replaced be those from `$_GET`) - this is a security hole... Also use a `mysql_real_escape_string()` method when using with MySQL or escape the user input by other method...

Comment: Yes, I will escape the data when the script is working.  Right now, it is just me tinkering with it.  I will use escapes and sprintf when I have this one part working.

Comment: If you cannot adjust the HTML, you're in a very rough spot. You are looking for a way to avoid a behaviour that you have programmed, effectively.

Comment: Right.  I understand it is odd.  If it's not possible, it's not possible--oh well.  But there is an ASP script that does a similar thing, so I thought there must be a way to do it in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this if you are using $_GET:

```
function convertInput($qs=""){
  $rtn = "";
  $holdingArray = array();
  if(trim($qs)!=""){
    $vars = explode("&", $qs);
    foreach($vars as $val){
      $kv = explode("=", $val);
      if(count($kv)==2){
        if(isset($holdingArray[$kv[0]])){
          $holdingArray[$kv[0]] .= "," . $kv[1];
        }else{
          $holdingArray[$kv[0]] = $kv[1];
        }
      }
    }
    $rtn = $holdingArray;
  }
  return $rtn;
}
print_r(convertInput($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]));
```

Comment: You understand that the OP can't change the HTML?

Comment: Are you using POST or GET on your forms?

Comment: @Wiseguy yeah I know but for some reason I cannot comment on the question

Comment: It is a post method.  I changed it to Get in testing so I could see the query string, but the end result must use Post.

Comment: There is a *small* chance that you can extract the data you desire without changing the HTML. I'll post something.

Comment: OK Cool, I have just added some code that will produce the correct result :)

Comment: if you are using "POST" use: 

`print_r(convertInput(file_get_contents("php://input")));`

instead of:

`print_r(convertInput($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]));`

Comment: To make it work with your code you could always do something like: `$_REQUEST = convertInput(file_get_contents("php://input"));` :)

Comment: This gets me closer!  Thanks a lot for the suggestion.  There are problems with my script as it is, but I can see the array when I print.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$keys = array();
$values = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){ //So, it will loop through the form data
    if (!array_search($key, $keys)){ //Checking to see if the key has been used yet
        $keys[] = $key;
    } else {
        $values[$key][] = array($key=>$value);
    }
}
```

This should build an array of your `FORM SELECT` choices built from the same form, provided that the data is preserved from the browser and is logically eliminated (when accessed as an array, only the last element of the same associated key is preserved, but otherwise the data is there to be had) instead of procedurally eliminated.

I have no idea if this works, because this is building from a theory, not from any kind of documentation or code expertise.

Answer (score 0):

PHP parses the request string (query string or x-www-form-urlencoded) into $_GET, $_POST, and $_REQUEST arrays using the rule that when the same key is present multiple times, later key values overwrite previous ones. So if you cannot change the key names on the forms to append `[]` like PHP expects, you have to access the raw query string and parse it by hand.

Note that repeating the key name without `[]` creates ambiguity as to whether a query string key is meant to be a scalar or an array. You will have to decide how to resolve that.  E.g., you can use a server-defined hardcoded list of names with array values.

This is how you could process a query string into a *list* of values:

```
function paramlist($querystring, $raw=false) {
    $plist = array();
    $decoder = ($raw) ? 'rawurldecode' : 'urldecode';
    $pairs = explode('&', $querystring);
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        $plist[] = array_map($decoder, explode('=', $pair, 2));
    }
    return $plist;
}
```

If you have a query string like `a=1&b=2&a=3`, this function will return `array(array('a','1'),array('b','2'),array('a','3'))`. You can then turn that to an associative array using any logic you want.

However, you need to get the query or form string in the first place:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST'
    and $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']==='application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {
   // form body
   $qs = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
} else {
   // url query string
   $qs = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
```

Note that if you send a form encoded with `multipart/form-data`, PHP *will not let you access the raw request* (even `php://input` will not work), so in this case there is *no way* to reprocess the form variables. Sorry!